# How can I emulate Atari games on my iMac

Tags: install, games

I am trying to play "[Trailblazer](http://www.atarimania.com/game-atari-st-trailblazer_10673.html)", an old Atari game, on my 2011 iMac.
I installed an emulator called "[Stella](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11351/stella/reviews)". I have ROMs for this game in .bin, .stx, .tap, .cas, .atr, .cpgz, .st formats, but only the .bin can be recognized by Stella? Is that normal?

And at first the .bin ROMs appeared in the "browse" window of Stella, now they are all gone; but they still are in the folder, though, why? Would love some help figuring it out :) 
I've heard there is a manual for Stella, but I couldn't find it anywhere. I might also need help configuring the keyboard unless you can point me to some documentation.

PS: Please, if you have the right credentials, add "emulator" and "retro-gaming" as tags? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please add comment to explain downvotes. Sneaky behaviours might be endorsed on S.E. but are still frowned upon IRL.

Comment: Any links to Stella?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your .bin, so I can test it out.

Comment: @MatteoGuarnerio
http://ge.tt/2GONPiL2/v/0

Comment: This question seems to be dead. Anyone had luck at running this?